# choosing an app name for azure function when publishing via vs

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, function, azure-functions

When publishing a function to Azure they are asking for a name, I understand that this is the app name, should it be the same for all functions on this project?
Does it make a different other then the address of the app:
http://.azurewebsites.net/api/
?

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are naming is a Function App. This is similar to an App Service, but then targeted at running your Functions.

> A function app provides an execution context in Azure in which your functions run. As such, it is the unit of deployment and management for your functions. A function app is comprised of one or more individual functions that are managed, deployed, and scaled together. All of the functions in a function app share the same pricing plan, deployment method, and runtime version. Think of a function app as a way to organize and collectively manage your functions.

Source: [Azure Functions developer guide - Function app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob#function-app)

In short:

1. All Functions in one Function App are deployed, maintained and scaled together.
2. All Functions in one Function App (if HttpTriggered) have the same base address `<function-app-name>.azurewebsites.net`
3. Next to points 1 and 2, it does not make a difference other than the address

Answer (score 0):

https://**< functionName>**.azurewebsites.net/api/**< triggerName>**

> https://**< functionName>**.azurewebsites.net This is the Application name, should it be the same for all functions

In your Azure Function App, only **triggers** will be **different**, the **Function APP** name should be the **same** for all.

http://**< functionName>**.azurewebsite.net You can use the same Function App name for all triggers in your function app.

Below is the triggers if you want to use the specific trigger the function URL will be like https://**< functionName>**.azurewebsites.net/api/

[image]